# How to change [UIApplication sharedApplication].window orientation along with device in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow, uiapplication

In my application I want to add UIview as a subview on AppDelegate.Window. UIView frame is (0,0,1024,768). After adding view on window it covers only half of the screen.

What I understood is view dimensions are screen landscape dimensions. Window is in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to give dynamic width and height, rather that fix it by 1024 and 768. You can pass like, AppDelegate.Window.bounds.width and AppDelegate.Window.bounds.height.

Like.

```
 CGRectMake (0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
```